# Trying to pull values out of hash table based on binary value in Powershell

Tags: powershell, binary, hashtable, operations

Ok have an interesting problem I am working on at work.  We are migrating our user, app, and shared storage to a completely different system; however perms were set up with a mix of both local groups and domain level global groups.  Problem is Local groups can't migrate directly over so I am having to correct those permissions using a Matrix of what global groups belong to what groups local to the device.  Simple enough and I have that working.

Now the issue I have ran into is that a user may have rights given to it through local groups (say read and write) and then a separate set of rights (say modify and Read&Execute) given through global permissions.  So my solution to that was build a list of rights assigned to a binary value (i.e. 1=Read, 2=write, 4=read and execute) which then gives me a value I can use to do a binary OR operation on to make sure they get all of the rights they should have from across the groups.

Now my question is once I have the ORed binary value how can I use it against the existing list to pull out the individual rights to assign in the set-acl call?  Any ideas and pointers are very much appreciated.

Comment: How many bits do you need to OR together?

Answer (score 0):

Given the hashtable:

```
$permissions = @{read=1;write=2;readAndExecute=4}
```

And the value of the binary or operation:

```
$oredBinary = 7 # All permissions
```

You could check like so:

```
$permissions.GetEnumerator() | Where-Object { ($_.Value -band $oredBinary) -ne 0} | Select @{n='Permissions';e={$_.Name}}
```